# Using load() and onLoad()

Tags: jquery, onload

I have a few pages with the same header and footer. I want to use jQuery load function as -

```
$("#header").load("template.html  #template_h1");   
$("#footer").load("template.html  #template_f1");
```

My problem:

- The pages already include a script with onload function, that
  converts some span tags to new format.
- My header and footer do use this span tags that need to be converted.
- I cannot change the included script.
- I want my `load()` functions to run BEFORE the onload function.

I tried to run them in `$(document).ready(function()` but it is too late. the span tags in the header\footer are not converted.

Which event can I use?

Comment: try $(window).load(function() { ... });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could keep a reference of the onload function, do your stuff, then run the original onload function.  If you place this just inside the body tag or include it as a script after the script that generates the intial onload it should work as expected.

```
var oldOnLoad = window.onload;

window.onload = function() {
   oldOnLoad();
}
```

**EDIT** To clarify, you need to call `oldOnLoad` after the header and footer have downloaded.

```
var oldOnLoad = window.onload;
var headerComplete = false, footerComplete = false;

var callOldOnLoad = function() {
    if (headerComplete && footerComplete) {
        oldOnLoad();
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    $("#header").load("template.html  #template_h1", function() {
        headerComplete = true;
        callOldOnLoad();
    });   
   $("#footer").load("template.html  #template_f1", function() {
        footerComplete = true;
        callOldOnLoad();
    });
}
```

Haven't tested this, but you might run in to a problem of the DOM not updating before you call `oldOnLoad`.  So you may need to put that in a setTimeout.

```
setTimeout(function() {oldOnLoad();}, 0);
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this addresses the problem at all?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Well the problem he is having is he wants to do something before the already defined onload. By saving a reference and calling it after defining his own solves the problem. I updated my answer for more completeness.

Comment: Ahh, I understand now. Clever. (It doesn't solve the *core* problem that this is a very inefficient way to do templating, but it answers the question - +1)

Comment: @Pekka웃 I agree. My solution solves the problem but Atara should take your advice on a server side solution.

Answer (score 2):

`.load()` is asynchronous, so you can never rely on the elements getting loaded in time, no matter how early you make the call. You'd have to make the `.load()` synchronous (ie. block the page until it the request has finished) but that is a terrible idea.

This is not a good way to do templating IMO. Also, you're likely to slow down your page load significantly by requiring two requests to complete before the page looks right.

If at all possible, include these template parts from server side.

Comment: Thanks. 1. What is the corrext way for templating is such case? 2. Can I use Seain Malkin solution?

Comment: 1. The easiest way would be to use a server side language to include the template parts. 2. As far as I can see, Sean's solution doesn't really address the problem.

Comment: @Atara correction, Sean's solution *does* address the problem (but my point still stands, this is not a good way to do things)

Answer (score -1):

Just place your code inside the `<body>` just after you define the `header` and `footer` elements in HTML.

Example:

```
<body>
    <div id="header">Foo</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#header").load("template.html  #template_h1");
    </script>

    <!-- Other Content -->

    <div id="footer">Bar</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#footer").load("template.html  #template_f1");
    </script>
</body>
```

Also, you can place the CSS inclusion at end of the file to load the CSS after your code.

Comment: Nope. `.load()` is asynchronous. This will not work the way he needs.